# How to list only security groups in AAD using ms graph api?

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-sdks

According to the on-line docs at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/groups-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0 there are four AAD groups: Office365, security, email-enabled security, and distribution.

I'm using the following to list groups:

```
        graphGroupsPages = await graphServiceClient.Groups
            .Request()
            //.Filter(????) <= if yes, what should it be?
            .GetAsync();
```

I've seen an example of how to list Office365 (Unified) groups.

How do I list security groups only?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Based on the document, you should list the groups whose `mailEnabled` is false and `securityEnabled` is true.

```
var graphGroupsPages = await graphServiceClient.Groups.Request().Filter("mailEnabled eq false and securityEnabled eq true").GetAsync();
```